# Two color values one for h1 title and one for the background with html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to save two values one for the h1 tag and one for the body background I let th user select the color 1 and color 2 now when i press on the third button all changes have to be aplied and the color has to change I tryed but with no luck :(

(html)

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>All the elements</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>


    <div class="h1tag">

<ul>
    <h1> dit is een title</h1>
    <li>paragraaf 1: Ik ging op reis</li>
    <li>paragraaf 2: en ik nam mee</li>
    <li>paragraaf 3: een stekkerdoos</li>
    <li>paragraaf 4: en een zaklamp</li>


</ul>
</div>




        <button type="button" onclick="saveUserData()"class="button0">achtergrond kleur opslaan</button>
        <input id="kleur0" type="color" value="#ff0000">

        <button type="button" onclick="saveUserdata()"class="button1">titel kleur opslaan</button>
        <input id="kleur1" type="color" value="#ff0000">

        <button onclick="myFunction()">kleuren toepassen op pagina</button>

    </body>




<footer>
<script defer src="script.js"></script>
</footer>
</html>
```

(javascript)

```
unction myFunction(){ 
var matches = document.querySelector(".h1");
var button0 = document.getElementById("kleur0").value;

var matches = document.querySelector(".h1tag");
var button1 = document.getElementById("kleur1").value;

return document.body.style.backgroundColor = kleur0.kleur1;
}
```

Comment: Hi what error are you getting ?
i see you forgot "f" in function could that be the issue ?
if not I suggest you use the example here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_queryselector_class

notice that h1 has a class name that is used to reference it in js code

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you were doing wrong is not allocating it to the right variables ..

working code here under .

```js
function myFunction(){ 
var matches = document.querySelector("h1");
var button0 = document.getElementById("kleur0").value;

//var matches = document.querySelector(".h1tag");
var button1 = document.getElementById("kleur1").value;

 document.body.style.backgroundColor = button0;
matches.style.color = button1;
}
```

```html
0


I need to save two values one for the h1 tag and one for the body background I let th user select the color 1 and color 2 now when i press on the third button all changes have to be aplied and the color has to change I tryed but with no luck :(

(html)

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>All the elements</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>


    <div class="h1tag">

<ul>
    <h1> dit is een title</h1>
    <li>paragraaf 1: Ik ging op reis</li>
    <li>paragraaf 2: en ik nam mee</li>
    <li>paragraaf 3: een stekkerdoos</li>
    <li>paragraaf 4: en een zaklamp</li>


</ul>
</div>




        <button type="button" onclick="saveUserData()"class="button0">achtergrond kleur opslaan</button>
        <input id="kleur0" type="color" value="#ff0000">

        <button type="button" onclick="saveUserdata()"class="button1">titel kleur opslaan</button>
        <input id="kleur1" type="color" value="#ff0000">

        <button onclick="myFunction()">kleuren toepassen op pagina</button>

    </body>




<footer>
<script defer src="script.js"></script>
</footer>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply my code works fine now :)